# Browser doesn't load local images while using SDL2 + emscripten

Tags: javascript, c++, sdl-2, emscripten

I am trying to port SDL2 c++ code to JS using emscripten. My current filesystem looks like this (upper case for folders and lower case for files):

```
C
|-VC
   |-SDL
       |-test.cpp
       |-RESOURCES
              |-hello.bmp
```

'hello.bmp' is any 640x480 px bitmap while 'test.cpp' contains the next source code:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
#include <emscripten.h>
#endif

struct context
{
    SDL_Renderer *ren;
    SDL_Texture *tex;
};

void mainloop(void* arg)
{
    context *con = static_cast<context*>(arg);
    SDL_RenderClear(con->ren);
    SDL_RenderCopy(con->ren, con->tex, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(con->ren);
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "SDL_Init Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Window *win = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World!", 100, 100, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (win == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "SDL_CreateWindow Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Renderer *ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    if (ren == nullptr)
    {
        SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
        std::cout << "SDL_CreateRenderer Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

    std::string imagePath = "Resources/hello.bmp";
    SDL_Surface *sur = SDL_LoadBMP(imagePath.c_str());
    if (sur == nullptr)
    {
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
        std::cout << "SDL_LoadBMP Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Texture *tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, sur);
    SDL_FreeSurface(sur);
    if (tex == nullptr)
    {
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
        std::cout << "SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
    context con = { ren, tex };
    emscripten_set_main_loop_arg(mainloop, &con, -1, 1);
#else
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        SDL_RenderClear(ren);
        SDL_RenderCopy(ren, tex, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(ren);
        SDL_Delay(1000);
    }
#endif

    SDL_DestroyTexture(tex);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

I am using Windows 10 and emscripten 1.38.21. I am trans-compiling with the next command line in a console within dir "C:\emsdk-master\emscripten\1.38.21":

```
emcc c:/vc/sdl/test.cpp -O2 -s USE_SDL=2 -s USE_SDL_IMAGE=2 -s --preload-file c:/vc/sdl/Resources -o prueba.html
```

The problem is that once hello.html has been generated I open it in Firefox 64.0 browser, and the next error text is shown:

```
SDL_LoadBMP Error: Couldn't open Resources/hello.bmp
```

In Chrome 71.0 an exception is launched and program halts.

Please, any help with this for both Firefox / Chrome browsers?

Comment: Try -s SDL2_IMAGE_FORMATS='["bmp","png"]' .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but maybe this args combination will help you.
 It's good to put -lSDL , emcc will handle other problems with linking libs.

You need first go to the current dir.

```
 cd c:/vc/sdl/
```

In this way we will use only relative paths.

```
 emcc test.cpp -s USE_SDL=2 -lSDL --preload-file Resources -s USE_SDL_IMAGE=2 -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 --use-preload-plugins -s SDL2_IMAGE_FORMATS='["bmp","png"]' -s GL_UNSAFE_OPTS=0  -o prueba.html
```